# What's the API that GMail uses, to notify browser tabs for incoming emails?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, dom

I've been using FF4 for a week now and I have my GMail Inbox always open in a tab, that I have pinned as an "app tab". I noticed that when I get a new email, the tab get a light blue light, which notifies my visually that I have new unread email.

What API is GMail using to notify the tab (window) for unread emails?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081421/javascript-to-check-gmail-unread-count

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Browser Window Blink in Task Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Answer (score 7):

Firefox flashes the app tab when the page title changes.

Gmail's title looks something like "Gmail - Inbox (5) - foo@gmail.com" where the '5' is the number of unread messages.  When gmail sees new messages it changes the title accordingly, and that causes the app tab to flash.

Answer (score 1):

What it probably does is modify `document.title` which makes the window flash.